# Apify web scraper ignoring URL Fragment

Tags: javascript, apify

I have a list of URL that I want to scrape, so i put it into the `startUrls` like this

```
"startUrls": [
    {
      "url": "https://www.example.com/sample#000000",
      "method": "GET"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://www.example.com/sample#111111",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
```

And this is the excerpt from my `pageFunction` code.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
  const { request } = context;
  var name;
  try {
     name = document.querySelector('h1').textContent;
  } catch (e) {
     name = "null";
  }
  return {
     link: request.url,
     name
  };
}
```

It's working fine with URLs that can be differentiated with either the domain, or the path. But if the only difference is in the fragment, only the first URL is processed as the second URL is considered a duplicate and therefore skipped.

i've tried adding this bit of code at the second line of the `pageFunction`

```
await context.enqueueRequest({
  url: context.request.url,
  keepUrlFragment: true,
});
```

But it leads up to another problem that it's producing duplicate results for each URL.

So what should I do to make this work correctly? Is there another way than calling `enqueueRequest` to set the `keepUrlFragment` to `true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot set `keepUrlFragment` directly in startUrls now. So I propose to not use them at all. You can instead pass them as an array in `customData`. Then you can use page function like this with a dummy startUrl like `http://example.com` and label `START`

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
  const { request, customData } = context;
  if (request.userData.label === 'START') {
     for (const url of customData) {
        await context.enqueueRequest({
          url,
          keepUrlFragment: true,
        });  
     }
  } else {
     // Your main scraping logic here
  }

}
```